# Nagios not sending emails

Tags: nagios

Nagios is not sending emails. I see the logs that it shows alerts but no emails are going out. Any suggestions to debug the issue?

/var/log/maillog doesn't show any log entry. Manually sending emails through command line do reach my inbox.

Log and config:

```
[1549711074] SERVICE FLAPPING ALERT: host001;Disk Space - /boot;STARTED; Service appears to have started flapping (21.6% change >= 20.0% threshold)
[1549711074] SERVICE FLAPPING ALERT: host001;Disk Space Warn Only - /boot;STARTED; Service appears to have started flapping (21.6% change >= 20.0% threshold)
[1549711194] SERVICE ALERT: host001;Disk Space - /boot;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;/boot: 100%used(98MB/99MB) (>90%) : CRITICAL
[1549711194] SERVICE ALERT: host001;Disk Space Warn Only - /boot;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;/boot: 100%used(98MB/99MB) (>90%) : CRITICAL
[1549711254] SERVICE ALERT: host001;Disk Space - /boot;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;/boot: 100%used(98MB/99MB) (>90%) : CRITICAL
[1549711254] SERVICE ALERT: host001;Disk Space Warn Only - /boot;CRITICAL;SOFT;2;/boot: 100%used(98MB/99MB) (>90%) : CRITICAL
[1549711314] SERVICE ALERT: host001;Disk Space - /boot;CRITICAL;HARD;3;/boot: 100%used(98MB/99MB) (>90%) : CRITICAL
[1549711314] SERVICE ALERT: host001;Disk Space Warn Only - /boot;CRITICAL;HARD;3;/boot: 100%used(98MB/99MB) (>90%) : CRITICAL
[1549711387] Caught SIGTERM, shutting down...
[1549711387] Successfully shutdown... (PID=28697)
[1549711387] Warning: aggregate_status_updates directive ignored.  All status file updates are now aggregated.
[1549711387] Nagios 3.0.6 starting... (PID=29699)
[1549711387] Local time is Sat Feb 09 03:23:07 PST 2019
[1549711387] LOG VERSION: 2.0
[1549711387] Finished daemonizing... (New PID=29700)
[1549711387] SERVICE FLAPPING ALERT: host001;Disk Space - /boot;STARTED; Service appears to have started flapping (27.3% change >= 20.0% threshold)
[1549711387] SERVICE FLAPPING ALERT: host001;Disk Space Warn Only - /boot;STARTED; Service appears to have started flapping (27.3% change >= 20.0% threshold)
[1549712107] SERVICE ALERT: mysql-db03;eth0 status;UNKNOWN;SOFT;1;ERROR: No snmp response from 10.49.64.62 (alarm)
[1549712107] SERVICE ALERT: mysql-db03;eth1 status;UNKNOWN;HARD;3;ERROR: No snmp response from 10.49.64.62 (alarm)
[1549712157] SERVICE ALERT: mysql-db03;eth0 status;OK;SOFT;2;OK: Interface eth0 (index 2) is up.
[1549712277] SERVICE ALERT: mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;HARD;3;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
[1549712277] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: rt;mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;ngmail;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
[1549712292] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: 724_shift11;mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;ngmail;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
[1549712307] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: skytel1;mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;ngmail;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
[1549712322] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: skytel2;mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;ngmail;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
[1549712337] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: skytel4;mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;ngmail;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
[1549712352] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: skytel6;mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;ngmail;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
[1549712367] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: skytel7;mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;ngmail;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
[1549712382] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: pubfolders;mysql-db03;eth1 status;CRITICAL;notify-by-email;CRITICAL: Interface eth1 (index 3) is administratively down.
```

and notification config:

```
# 'notify-by-email' command definition
define command{
        command_name    notify-by-email
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nNotification Number : $NOTIFICATIONNUMBER$\nProblem Duration: $SERVICEDURATION$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $SHORTDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n\n" | /bin/mail -r $ADMINEMAIL$ -s "**$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ alert #$NOTIFICATIONNUMBER$ - $HOSTALIAS$:$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$**" $CONTACTEMAIL$
        }

# 'host-notify-by-email' command definition
define command{
        command_name    host-notify-by-email
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nNotification Number : $NOTIFICATIONNUMBER$\nProblem Duration: $HOSTDURATION$\n\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nDate/Time: $SHORTDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info: \n$HOSTOUTPUT$\n\n" | /bin/mail -r $ADMINEMAIL$ -s "HOST DOWN alert #$NOTIFICATIONNUMBER$ - $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$" $CONTACTEMAIL$
```

Contacts.cfg

```
define contact{
    contact_name                    ops
    alias                           Ops Email
    service_notification_period     24x7
    host_notification_period        24x7
    service_notification_options    w,u,c,r
    host_notification_options       d,u,r
    service_notification_commands   notify-by-email
    host_notification_commands      host-notify-by-email
    email                           user@domain.com

    }
```

Comment: Is it set to send email on the first alert or the nth? (3rd usually)

Comment: where is that set? I'm not sure where to check

Comment: besides I don't think its the nth time issue. Because I increased and decreased /boot space usage multiple times and yet no alert was sent.

Comment: Is your mailserver at `/bin/mail`?

Comment: That's right. Its in /bin/mail.

Comment: Without seeing all of your nagios config files this is hard to debug. The fact that you aren't seeing any error messages from _trying_ to send email makes me think that nagios isn't trying(which you've noted). There are some other posts here about this same issue plus lots of hits from searching. Something isn't configured properly so you'll need to find a working config (lots of examples out there) and starting comparing.

Comment: I've been looking through other posts for over an hour. none of it helped me at all.

Comment: Seems it got resolved. At least when I stop nrpe it sends alerts. I'll continue looking into the service issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I stopped the nrpe service it sent the alert. It seems the contact.cfg only was set to send Down, Unreachable and Recovery alert.